# angular invalid version: 1.2.12 Error Bower

Tags: javascript, angularjs, bower

When I try this command `bower install angular`

gives me this result:

```
bower install angular
bower cloning git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git
bower cached git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git
bower fetching angular
bower checking out angular#v1.2.12-build.2216+sha.5850e61
bower error invalid version: 1.2.12-build.2216+sha.5850e61

There were errors, here's a summary of them:
- angular invalid version: 1.2.12-build.2216+sha.5850e61
```

Any help is very appreciated

Comment: The latest according to http://angularjs.org/ is 1.2.11 so looks like their getting a bit ahead of themselves here.  Perhaps you can specify to install 1.2.11 directly... currently I'm using 1.2.8 because I didn't see all of the dependencies I needed when using 1.2.9 which was released when I setup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The latest stable version seems to `1.2.11`, so try specifying a version like

```
bower install angular#1.2.11
```

According to their [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AngularJS#Releases)

`1.2.11, cryptocurrency-hyperdeflation` is the lastest stable version.

I suggest you visit their official website or wiki page before you run bower. It's also advisable to specifiy a version in future. This advice also applies to all other libraries you intend to use

Comment: Thank you man, it worked like a charm, it happens with angular-resource repository too.

Comment: This worked for me. It should also be noted that when installing other modules at the same time, to specify the matching version. for example, `bower install angular#1.2.11 angular-resource#1.2.11 angular-route#1.2.11 --save`